# Testing return value of spied methods using Jasmine

Tags: jquery, datatables, jasmine

Full disclosure...this is my first SO question. Please be kind if I leave anything out. ;-)

I'm starting to use [Jasmin](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) to test one of my client-side Javascript objects. This object in particular manages the use of a jQuery plugin called [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net). The managed DataTables component will call a couple custom render methods to determine what to display for a couple columns and I am trying to test those methods.

**The short question:** How can I test the return value of methods for which I need to put a spy on?

**The back story**

Here is an shrunk down version of my Javascript object:

```
function Table(elemId) {
    this._table = $('#'+elemId).dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "fnRender": function(oObj, id) { 
                    return Table.renderIdColumn(oObj, id, lTable); 
                }, 
                "aTargets": ["idColumn"], 
                "bUseRendered": false
            },{
                "fnRender": function(oObj, name) { 
                    return Table.renderNameColumn(oObj, name, lTable); 
                }, 
                "aTargets": ["nameColumn"], 
                "bUseRendered": false
            }
        ],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
}

Table.renderIdColumn = function(oObj, id, lTable) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" value="'  id + '" />';
};

Table.renderNameColumn = function(oObj, name, lTable) {
    var id = oObj.aData[0];
    return '<a href="/obj/edit/' + id + '">' + name + '</a>';
};
```

So when creating a Table object, I need to intercept the call to Table.RenderIdColumn and Table.renderNameColumn so that I can assert the results. Here is what I have in Jasmine so far:

```
describe("Table", function() {
    var lTable;

    // Write a DOM table that will be rendered by the jQuery DataTable plugin
    beforeEach(function() {
        $('<table id="storeTable"></table>').appendTo('body');
        var headerCellClasses = ["idColumn","nameColumn"];
        var headerRow = $('<tr></tr>');
        $.each(headerCellClasses, function(index, value) {
            headerRow.append('<th class="' + value + '"></th>')
        });
        $('<thead></thead>').append(headerRow).appendTo('#lTable');
        $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo('#lTable');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // First remove DataTables enhancements
        lTable.fnDestroy();
        // Now remove from DOM
        $('#lTable').remove();
    });

    describe("when edit links are shown", function() {
        it("should render a checkbox in ID column", function() {
            spyOn(Table, "renderIdColumn");
            lTable = initializeDataTable();
            var oSettings = lTable._table.fnSettings();
            var id = 1;
            var obj = {
                oSettings: oSettings,
                iDataColumn: 0,
                iDataRow: 0,
                mDataProp: 0,
                aData: oSettings.aoData[0]._aData
            }

            var expected = '<input type="checkbox" value="'+ id +'" />';
            expect(Table.renderIdColumn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj, id, lTable);
            var results = Table.renderIdColumn(obj, id, lTable);
            expect(results).toEqual(expected);
        });
        it("should render the name column with a proper link", function() {
            spyOn(Table, "renderNameColumn");
            lTable = initializeDataTable();
            var oSettings = lTable._table.fnSettings();
            var name = "Name";
            var obj = {
                oSettings: oSettings,
                iDataColumn: 3,
                iDataRow: 0,
                mDataProp: 3,
                aData: oSettings.aoData[0]._aData
            }

            var expected = '<a href="/obj/edit/1">Name</a>';
            expect(Table.renderNameColumn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj, name, lTable);
            var results = Table.renderNameColumn(obj, name, lTable);
            expect(results).toEqual(expected);
        });
    });

});

function initializeDataTable() {
    // Mock the AJAX call to the server from DataTables plugin
    spyOn($.fn.DataTable.defaults, "fnServerData").andCallFake(function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        var json = {
            iEcho: 1,
            iTotalRecords: 1,
            iTotalDisplayRecord: 1,
            aaData: [
                [1, "Name"]
            ]
        }
        fnCallback(json);
    });
    return new Table("lTable");
}
```

In both test cases, the variable "results" is 'undefined'. I need to test these methods to make sure they are rendering the correct HTML but I can't seem to figure out how to assert the return values. Once I have a spy on the method, it doesn't seem to return anything. I've tried inserting

```
Table.renderIdColumn.reset();
Table.renderNameColumn.reset();
```

But neither of those did anything...maybe because my methods are static? FYI, those methods are static because I can't properly assign the "spy" if they are instance methods. The Table constructor calls the DataTables plugin which will cause these methods to be called automatically so I can't construct a Table object and then put a spy on those methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `spyOn(Table, "renderIdColumn")`, you are (effectively) replacing `Table.renderIdColumn` with a function that doesn't return anything.

If you want to assert it was called and still return the results of the original, write `spyOn(Table, "renderIdColumn").andCallThrough()`.

The `.reset()` syntax you mentioned will only reset the spy's internal call counts (IIRC).

Comment: where do you check for the return value?